# Confusion about redefining constant using define directive(#define) in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

As far as I know, standard allows redefinition only if the new definition duplicates the old one. So for example,

If,

```
#define X 100
```

Then,

```
#define X 200 // Not allowed
#define X 100 // Allowed
```

But what confuses me is when the header file includes redefintion which doesn't duplicate the old defintion. For example,

There is a header file, `header.h` such that

```
#ifndef X
#define X 100
#endif
```

and source code `main.c` such that

```
#define X 10
#include "header.h"
```

Since `#define X 100` is below `#define X 10` in the `main` file, I thought this would occur error. But surprisingly, the compiler does not complain! Why is such behaviour allowed in C?

Comment: Why would you think that an error would occur? The *point* of `#ifndef` is to guard against the error that you are worried about.

Comment: Sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it doesn't, because `#define X 100` is never reached.

Think about this, what does `#ifndef` do?

Put the `#define X 10` below the `#include`, what happens now?